# Do I have to defensively protect nulls in my hql query?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

Say I have an company with a phone number. I might have a lead record and I want to get leads for a phone number. Do I have to ensure my company is not null first?

Option 1

```
FROM Lead l WHERE l.company IS NOT NULL AND l.company.phone = :phone
```

Option 2

```
FROM Lead l WHERE l.company.phone = :phone
```

In option 1 I'm making sure company is not null before I check for phone. In option 2 I assume hibernate has a way to short circuit that.

I've tried looking but can't find documentation on this fact. I'm also on mobile atm so that is hampering my search (and my posting this!)

Comment: That depends: will `l.company` ever be null?

Comment: Yes it is possible. For example a lead might be a person without a company. In fact my worry is the query will break if company is null, like a null pointer exception or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't. `where l.company.phone = :phone` is equivalent to `inner join l.company c where c.phone = :phone`, and an inner join will simply filter out the entities which have a null company.

Those queries are ultimately transformed to SQL and executed by the database. They don't use your Java entities. The corresponding SQL query would look like

```
from lead l, company c where l.company_id = c.id and c.phone = :phone
```

A simple test would have allowed you to find out by yourself, BTW.

Comment: I happen to be on a van ride to a convention with no easy way to test atm, but it's relevant to a discussion we're having on the ride. I appreciate the explanation!